Evaluating a Kloosterman-like sums at prime powers
I have the sum $$\sum _{A,A'=1\atop {A\equiv A'\text { mod}(d)\atop {(AA',q)=1}}}^{q}e\left (\frac {A+\overline A}{q}-\frac {A'+\overline {A'}}{q}\right )$$ and want to evaluate it for $q=p^2$ and $d=p$. If I first do the $A'$ sum the above becomes $$\sum _{A=1\atop {(A,q)=1}}^qe\left (\frac {A+\overline A}{q}\right )\sum _{A'=1\atop {(A'd+A,q)=1}}^{q/d}e\left (-\frac {A'd+A}{q}-\frac {\overline {A'd+A}}{q}\right )=\sum _{A=1\atop {(A,q)=1}}^qe\left (\frac {\overline A}{q}\right )\sum _{A'=1}^{q/d}e\left (-\frac {A'}{q/d}-\frac {\overline {A'd+A}}{q}\right )$$ but I'm not sure what I can do here. Is there anything I can do to deal with the term $\overline {A'd+A}$? I feel like I'm missing a trick from congruences or elementary number theory.
Note that I can do the case where $q=dQ$ with $(Q,d)=1$ and of course the case $q=d$.

For $p$ odd, this is
$$\sum_{\substack{a,b \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \\ a \equiv b \pmod{p}}} e\left(\frac{a + \overline{a} - b - \overline{b}}{p^2}\right).$$
We make the change of variables $a = b + cp$, where now $c \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so that $\overline{a} \equiv \overline{b} - \overline{b}^2 cp \pmod{p^2}$. The sum becomes
$$\sum_{\substack{b \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \\ c \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}} e\left(\frac{(1 - \overline{b}^2)c}{p}\right).$$
The sum over $c$ vanishes unless $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, in which case it is $p$. If $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, then $b \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$, so that $b \equiv cp \pm 1 \pmod{p^2}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. So there are $2p$ coprime congruence classes $b \pmod{p^2}$ for which $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, and consequently the sum is equal to $2p^2$.

thank you! (in the meantime i learnt that kloosterman sums have explicit expressions for for moduli $p^2$, at least in terms of the legendre symbol, but i think i can certainly still learn from your answer too)
